# FindAsync() gives null

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have the following line of code that returns null, and I cannot figure out why.

```
var meting = await this.Context.MetingenView.FindAsync(key);
```

key is 1 in this example.
I have Context defined, and it works for other requests, so the issue doesn't lay with that.

Comment: Do you actually have something which has that key?

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.findasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) say "_If no entity is found in the context or the store, then null is returned._", which would suggest, as @Sean mentioned, that there's nothing available with that key. Have you checked?

Comment: How do you mean? I do use it before to get an entity, and with that it does work.

Comment: var entity = await this.Context.MetingenView.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(g => g.IdMeting == key);


this returns something succesfully

Comment: Is `IdMeting` a primary key?

Comment: @Diado Yes, and I defined that with [Key] too

Comment: Can you share the model class code?

Comment: Maybe you should check first if the ModelState is valid and then use the FindAsync method.